# How do we determine the axis aand index_y in the merge?

Tags: python, dataframe, data-analysis

I am new to data analysis and python. I came acroos the following

```
df1.merge(df2,  on='cnpj',suffixes=('','_y')).drop('index_y',axis=1)
```

for performing merge operations among the dataframes. I would like to know how the `axis` and `index_y` is determined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overlapping columns between df1 and df2  will me renamed according to the specified suffix, so "nothing" for df1 ("") and "_y" for df2.

Afterwards you drop the column "index_y" (which is the index of df2 with the suffix _y) by setting axis=1 (axis=0 along rows).  This operation is performed after the merge to most likely get rid of redundant information.